# Limit of making PUT request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, request

I have a weird problem while I try to make the same PUT request multiple times, it works for about 8,9 times but after I have to refresh the page to work again.

I use React with Node.js (using Sequelize) for request:

React code:

```
return await axios
    .put(`${API_URL}/api/user/createUser`, {
      id_game_table: gameTableId,
      name: nickName,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return [response.data, null];
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return [null, error.response];
    });
```

My Node.js body destructuring:

[image: nodejs-body]

What my Node.js looks like:

[image]

And the requests I was making:

[image]

Here, we can see that the first 9 PUT request was a success - this can be seen even in Node.js - but after 9 PUT requests was made all requests that I made was just OPTIONS and no other request was made. As another mention, there is not output in console.

The config for Node.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const index = require("./routes/index");
const port = process.env.PORT || 4001;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(index);
app.use("/api/gameTable", require("./routes/gameTable.routes"));
app.use("/api/user", require("./routes/user.routes"));

const io = socketIo(server, { cors: { origin: "*" } });

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Note: The socket connection doesn't matter, I know that I had this request limit behaviour as well when using Angular with Spring in the past (without socket).

Comment: you could have tried to do the same with postman or plain old curl to see if it's a server  issue or client issue...

Comment: From what I see with Postman I can do as many requests as I want. But I don't think this is a server error anyway because after 9 requests I don't receive any request on server.

Comment: Then you should re-write the question focussing only on client.

Comment: on client it could be any thing from library issue to client not able to get a port.